# Convert text file with 3 columns into nested dict of dict in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a txt file as below:

```
#FromNodeId  ToNodeId    Weight
B   A   5
B   D   1
B   G   2
A   B   5
A   D   3
A   E   12
A   F   5
D   B   1
D   G   1
D   E   1
D   A   3
G   B   2
G   D   1
G   C   2
C   G   2
C   E   1
C   F   16
E   A   12
E   D   1
E   C   1
E   F   2
F   A   5
F   E   2
F   C   16
```

I want to convert this into a graph as dict of dicts in python as below:

```
graph = {
'B': {'A': 5, 'D': 1, 'G': 2},
'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 12, 'F' :5},
'D': {'B': 1, 'G': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 3},
'G': {'B': 2, 'D': 1, 'C': 2},
'C': {'G': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 16},
'E': {'A': 12, 'D': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 2},
'F': {'A': 5, 'E': 2, 'C': 16}}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Using pandas?..

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Could you please help?

Comment: I asked you if you're using pandas or not...

Comment: I'm not using pandas. I am trying to convert in dict of dict format because my Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the shortest path needs to be in this format.

Comment: So far i have used the following code: g = nx.read_edgelist('sample2.txt', nodetype=str,
data=(('weight',float),), create_using=nx.DiGraph())


graph = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(g,edge_data = None)

Comment: Please edit your question and put this code in there. It's vital to a good question that you show what you've already tried.

Comment: Yeah I'll just post it again. Sorry that its not in a good format now since I'm using stack overflow for the first time to post a question

Comment: Also, while you're at it, explain why that code doesn't work. Does it give a wrong value, or throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in your data and group by first value (FromNodeId):

```
import itertools, re
file_data = [[*a, int(b)] for *a, b in [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')]]
last_results = {a:dict(i[1:] for i in b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(file_data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 12, 'F': 5}, 'B': {'A': 5, 'D': 1, 'G': 2}, 'C': {'G': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 16}, 'D': {'B': 1, 'G': 1, 'E': 1, 'A': 3}, 'E': {'A': 12, 'D': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 2}, 'F': {'A': 5, 'E': 2, 'C': 16}, 'G': {'B': 2, 'D': 1, 'C': 2}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv, collections


tree = collections.defaultdict(dict)
with open(filepath) as fd: 
    reader = csv.reader(fd, delimiter = ' ', skipinitialspace = True)
    for row in reader:
        tree[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You commented your original code to be:

```
g = nx.read_edgelist('sample2.txt', nodetype=str, data=(('Weight', int),), create_using=nx.DiGraph())
graph = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(g,edge_data = None)
```

Which returns something like:

```
{'A': {'B': {'Weight': 5},
  'D': {'Weight': 3},
  'E': {'Weight': 12},
  'F': {'Weight': 5}},
 'B': {'A': {'Weight': 5}, 'D': {'Weight': 1}, 'G': {'Weight': 2}},
 'C': {'E': {'Weight': 1}, 'F': {'Weight': 16}, 'G': {'Weight': 2}},
 'D': {'A': {'Weight': 3},
  'B': {'Weight': 1},
  'E': {'Weight': 1},
  'G': {'Weight': 1}},
 'E': {'A': {'Weight': 12},
  'C': {'Weight': 1},
  'D': {'Weight': 1},
  'F': {'Weight': 2}},
 'F': {'A': {'Weight': 5}, 'C': {'Weight': 16}, 'E': {'Weight': 2}},
 'G': {'B': {'Weight': 2}, 'C': {'Weight': 2}, 'D': {'Weight': 1}}}
```

This is close, you can clean this up manually using a dictionary comprehension:

```
clean_graph = {a: {b: edge['Weight'] for b, edge in a_vals.items()} for a, a_vals in graph.items()}
```

Which produces:

```
{'A': {'B': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 12, 'F': 5},
 'B': {'A': 5, 'D': 1, 'G': 2},
 'C': {'E': 1, 'F': 16, 'G': 2},
 'D': {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'E': 1, 'G': 1},
 'E': {'A': 12, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'F': 2},
 'F': {'A': 5, 'C': 16, 'E': 2},
 'G': {'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 1}}
```

Comment: @VinilThombrey Please "accept" the answer that best solves your problem (checkmark just below the up/down arrows on the left) to make clear that your problem is solved

Comment: I just did. I didn't know about it. Thanks :)